# How to view or export the paths of the photos in a LibreOffice presentation?

Tags: libreoffice

I created a slideshow and drag-and-dropped photos into it. In doing so, I also selected the best images. I would like to view the names of those images in the slideshow or export them into a text file.

For example, this would help if I want to make a version similar to the slideshow in HTML. I would like to get:

```
slide 1: image1.jpeg
slide 2: image2.jpeg, image3.jpeg, image4.png
...
slide 10: picture.jpg
```

And I can then use the text file to produce an HTML file with similar content, or check for differences in presentation versions with a tool like `git`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-posted from the [LibreOffice help](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/233043/how-to-view-or-export-the-paths-of-the-photos-in-a-presentation/):

> as far as I understand XML file document.xml (which is part of the .odp ZIP container) it doesn't contain any information of the original file name and its location, if you drag-and-dropped it into the presentation (i.e. you embedded the image into the presentation). Embedded images get referenced by XML elements similar to
>
> `<draw:image xlink:href="Pictures/10000201000002A4000001D85A475B71F81A2EF0.png`,
>
> which don't contain any name information of the original name any longer.
>
> Thus from my point of view the answer is: **No**, this is not possible

If I had included them as a link instead of embedding, with `Insert > Image > Options: [x] Link`, I could find the list from the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I'm away from LibreOffice for a long time. But you can try these:

- While editing your slide, right click the image. There should be an option as "save", "save as image" or "export" or something like that.
- Get lost at the export menu. Try to find something suitable for you.
- Right click the image and choose something like "change". If you're lucky, you might start looking from the image's real path. But it's a long shot really.

1st option should do the trick for you. Yet, I still don't get "export them into a text file.". Your images, into a text file?

Comment: The closest is the export as HTML, where LibreOffice exports the presentation to a text file and images that can show the presentation in a web browser. Each slide has its own image, e.g. `image0.png` for the first slide, and I would like the name of the input images that go into that slide instead of the "output name." I updated the question to clarify what I wanted. You were not sure if this question belonged in this forum: where would you suggest I ask questions about using LibreOffice?

Comment: ask.libreoffice.org maybe?